# Is there any specification to tell me how JDBC and oledb works on tcp

Tags: jdbc, tcp, oledb

I'm working on a tcp intercept proxy.
I want to decode the binary tcp stream, exctract the information, modify it and encode and pass the tcp packets.

But I cannot find any clue, to show me how the JDBC/oledb encode their connection string to the tcp layer.

Is there any specification?

Comment: JDBC has nothing to do with it. It's just an API. What you're looking for is the wire protocol used by `oledb` clients. Which you will find with that product. Maybe. Not here.

Comment: JDBC only defines the Java interfaces to access a database, it does not specify anything about the wire protocol used (a driver may even not use TCP at all), because that is up to the individual database systems and their driver(s).